# the line integral. $\int _{C}\frac{1}{e^{z}+1}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, line-integrals

I want to solve the line integral.
$$f\left( z\right) =\dfrac{1}{e^{z}+1}$$
$$\int _{C}\dfrac{1}{e^{z}+1}dz$$
$C$ is a circle with a radius of 1 centered on 1.

I think this.

---

$$e^{z}+1=0$$
So $z=3i\pi$ is isolated singularity.
$$z=z\left( \theta \right) =-1+e^{i\theta }$$
$$\int _{0}^{2\pi }\dfrac{ie^{i\theta }}{e^{-1+e^{i\theta}}+1}=\int _{0}^{2\pi }\dfrac{ie^{i\theta +e^{i}\theta }}{e^{e^{i}\theta }+e}d\theta$$
I don't know what to do next. Please tell me.
By the way, the answer is [enter link description here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%5B0%2C2%CF%80%5D%28ie%5Ei%CE%B8%2F%28e%5E%28-1%2Be%5Ei%CE%B8%29%2B1%29%29d%CE%B8&lang=ja)

Comment: There is no singularity inside the circle so the integral is $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can it be solved without calculation?

Comment: Yes, the value is $0$ by Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  thank you. I think again.